# Does the Rogue's Riposte stop the enemy's attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, rogue

Rogue's Riposte Strike (PHB1 Pg 118) says:

> Hit: 1[W] + Dexterity modifier damage. If the target attacks you before the start of your next turn, you make your riposte against the target as an immediate interrupt: a Strength vs. AC attack that deals 1[W] + Strength modifier damage.

PHB1 Pg 268 contains this definition for *Immediate Action, Interrupt*

> An immediate interrupt lets you jump in when a certain trigger condition arises, acting before the trigger resolves. If an interrupt invalidates a triggering action, that action is lost. For example, an enemy makes a melee attack against you, but you use a power that lets you shift away as an immediate interrupt. If your enemy can no longer reach you, the enemy’s attack action is lost.

And to fill out my background info, a dictionary definition of [Riposte](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riposte) from Mirriam-Webster:

> a fencer's quick return thrust following a parry

Since a riposte *includes* a parry, one would assume that you parry the attack, thereby negating it and then retaliate with a quick thrust of your blade. However, the example given for immediate interrupt in the PHB1 only mentions shifting out of reach, which Riposte Strike doesn't allow. Even the examples in the Rules Compendium on pg 195 are only related to moving out of the way and not parrying.

So my question is: Does a Rogue's Riposte Strike stop the attack that triggers it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No. The name and the "fluff" text in itallic at the begining of the power just do not matter.

The power Inescapable *Blade* can be used with a Hammer or a Flail for example.

The same is true for feats, races, classes, items and everything else. The name is just a (preferably) unique identifier, has no bearing on the actual rules.

If you can make it impossible for the enemy to finish his action, you can stop it. There are some ways:

- You kill the enemy with your Riposte
- You slide the enemy with your Riposte out of reach, Mark of Storm and a Lightning Weapon can do that
- You give him penalties on his attack, so big that the hit turns into a miss, Impending Doom Style, Eldaarich Guarded Practice or Red Cloak Student feats for example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12576/discussion-between-andras-and-mc-hambone)

Comment: Do **not** chat or discuss in comments. That is what the link to chat above is for.